# DIVs surrounding image (Probably easy answer)

Tags: css, html, width, fill

I have 3 `div`s in a header.

1. dynamic width
2. 55px wide with a background image
3. 200px wide

I'm trying to get the left `div` to fill the rest of the horizontal width, and I've read some answers already, but I can't seem to get them on the same line. I currently have:

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#666;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    width:80%;
    min-width:755px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#333;
    background:url(img);
}


.headerLeft{
    background-color:#333;
    height:64px;
    margin-right:255px;
}
.headerCenter{
    background:url(img);
    width:55px;
    height:79px;
    float:right;
}
.headerRight{
    background-color:#333;
    height:65px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:14px;
    float:right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="headerLeft">dfg</div>
        <div class="headerRight">dfg</div>
        <div class="headerCenter">dfg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The image itself is just a curve, and the `div`s on either side are aligned to accommodate the curve, with a background image that flows through the curve. The problem I'm having is that the right and center `div`s are dropping down below the left `div`, even though they are lining up properly so that the size should be correct. The heights and margins are just there to make everything line up, but can be ignored for now just so I can get everything on the same line at least. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: your class `header` doesnt have a width. Have you tried giving it one? Could you also provide me a quick http://jsfiddle.net please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just switch the order of your `div`s and they'll behave as you want:

```
<div class="headerRight">dfg</div>
<div class="headerCenter">dfg</div>
<div class="headerLeft">dfg</div>
```

Your issue right now is that `.headerLeft` is coming before the other `div`s in the document flow.  Once `.headerRight` and `.headerCenter` come first, `.headerLeft` will expand to fill the rest of the line.